# How can i split a partition on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, diskmanagement, fdisk, ovh

I just purchased a brand new server on OVH with disk specification: 2 x480GB of SSD  SOFT.
When i do df -h, the output is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G   13G  5.7G  69% /
devtmpfs         16G   12K   16G   1% /dev
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            3.2G  792K  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/md2        421G   17G  383G   5% /home
```

Mind you i have stored many files and then i realized that i need much bigger space for root. Now i could either replace the 2 /dev/root with /dev/md2 and change boot drive or i could partition /dev/md2 with is attached on home(the data there can be deleted, backup is there) into 2 parts 200GB each and then mount one of the partition to /var/www/tmp to store the files needed during the working of sites. or i can resize the root partition. 
Output of lsblk is :

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0  19.5G  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0  19.5G  0 raid1 /
├─sda2    8:2    0 427.1G  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0 427.1G  0 raid1 /home
└─sda3    8:3    0   511M  0 part  [SWAP]
sdb       8:16   0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0  19.5G  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0  19.5G  0 raid1 /
├─sdb2    8:18   0 427.1G  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0 427.1G  0 raid1 /home
└─sdb3    8:19   0   511M  0 part  [SWAP]
```

Now i dont know which partition to edit.
I thought to do somthing like this, sudo fdisk /dev/sda2  (/home) and then delete the partition and then create 2 equal but now i can't decide it. Should i do it on /dev/sda2 or /dev/sdb2. What is the difference?

thank you for the help and i know it's a confusing question.

Answer (score 2):

In your position I would either

Reinstall the OS and configure the partitions that I wanted rather than accepting the ones that OVH provided. This is fairly straightforward using the OVH manager to access the remote conole. Just download a suitable ISO to your local machine and attach it as an iso device to the remote console then reboot and install as you would normally.

or

Easier is to move the files into /home somewhere and then bind mount that to /var/www e.g (after stopping relevant services).

```
mkdir /home/somewhere
mv /var/www/* /home/somewhere
mount -bind /home/somewhere /var/www
```

If this works for you then don't forget to add an entry to /etc/fstab

```
/home/somewhere /var/www    none    bind
```

or

Change the document root (or whatever) to be somewhere in /home.

Comment: Reinstalling is my preferred method of dealing with OVH. Their templates are shit.

Comment: Yes indeed and mine too.

Comment: by reinstalling here you mean first  i set up the partitions and then install the os all over again right?

Comment: No I mean you set up the partitions as part of the OS reinstall.